# multiple Images are not fully uploaded to S3 upon first lambda call

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless

i have issue with uploading multiple files to s3.
what my lambda is doing: 
1. uploading single file to s3 ( always work).
2. resizing the file to 4 new sizes (using sharp).
3. upload the resized files to s3.

the problem : sometimes only 2 or 3 out of 4 resized files are uploaded.
the surprising thing is that i noticed that on the next upload - the missing files from previous upload are added.

have no errors, i was thinking that this can be async issue so i awaited the right places to make it Synchronous.

will appreciate any help.

async function uploadImageArrToS3(resizeImagesResponse) {

```
return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
    var params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        ACL: 'public-read'
    };

    let uploadImgArr = resizeImagesResponse.map(async (buffer) => {
        params.Key = buffer.imgParamsArray.Key;
        params.Body = buffer.imgParamsArray.Body;
        params.ContentType = buffer.imgParamsArray.ContentType;

        let filenamePath = await s3.putObject(params, (e, d) => {
            if (e) {
                reject(e);
            } else {
                d.name = params.ContentType;
                return (d.name);
            }
        }).params.Key

        let parts = filenamePath.split("/");
        let fileName = parts[parts.length - 1]; 


        return {
            fileName: fileName,
            width: buffer.width
        };

    });

    await Promise.all(uploadImgArr).then(function (resizedFiles) {
        console.log('succesfully resized the image!');
        resolve(resizedFiles);
    });

})
```

}